# Wordpress programming video tutorials

Tags: plugins

I am a beginner in Wordpress programming. I am basically looking out for video tutorials that teach Wordpress programming and specifically creation of plugins and such advanced things. Are there any good video tutorials which teach such sort of stuff? or any courses from training companies like pluralsight. I know pluralsight is not into PHP but are there any other sites? I am even willing to pay for videos. The video tutorials need not be free however free is always welcome.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of sites I can refer:

1. Start with wordpress codex http://codex.wordpress.org/
2. http://net.tutsplus.com you may find good starting point there.
3. Search Youtube you can find some good ones there too.
4. And if you feel like paying for it try some tutorial series from http://lynda.com
5. Search google. I think its the best way to go :) there are hundreds of sites out there publishing written and video tutorials for beginners and advanced.